# WPFtoolkit, data added but with an offset

Tags: c#, string, charts, double, wpftoolkit

I want to plot data from funds, but when I add them to the wpftoolkit chart it gets an offset added, about +5. This results in the graph being painted outside of the chart area. Max vaule on the data is 259,66 but as you can see in the graph its above 265ish:

[image]

Here is the code in the xaml:

```
    <DVC:Chart Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="10" Name="Chart">
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:LineSeries Title="" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" Margin="0,-34,-14,-22">
            </DVC:LineSeries>
        </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
```

And adding data to the chart:

```
public IDictionary<DateTime, double> values { get; set; }

private void LoadLineChartData(Fund fund)
        {
            ((LineSeries)Chart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = fund.values;
        }
```

and this is how I convert string to double:

```
double.TryParse(valueString, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out valueDouble);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. 
Its the margin/padding that messes things up.